# Microsoft Excel - Grabbing values > 0

Tags: excel, if-statement

Is there any way using Microsoft excel to do an equation that does something like this:

IF(Condition, If true, If false) <-- Just in case, this is how an if statement is formatted

IF(a cell in a range has a value other than zero, put that/those value(s) here, do nothing)

For example:

[image]

IF(B1:B13 is something other than 0, grab that value, do nothing)

Based on the table above and the "equation" I am trying to figure out, it would return 12 and 17, 15.

Let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Comment: return how?  in two cells in a column, two cells in a row, or one cell delimited somehow?

Comment: If possible I'd like it returned in however many cells that are none zero numbers or in a single cell

Comment: What version of excel are you using ??

Comment: I am using the Microsoft 365 ProPlus Excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one has the Dynamic Array formula FILTER():

```
=FILTER(B2:B100,B2:B100<>0)
```

[image]

---

If not then put this in the first cell and copy down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($B$2:$B$100)/($B$2:$B$100<>0),ROW($ZZ1))),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your version of Excel supports`TEXTJOIN()`,use:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(B1:B13=0,"",B1:B13))
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

Some versions of Excel may require this formula to be array-entered.**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

Comment: I have the TEXTJOIN() but when I try to use it like you did, it only shows a blank cell. Do you know why it would do that?

Comment: @user85352  See my **EDIT#1**